# Como permitir apenas uma determinada palavra?

Tags: python

Como fazer com que apenas o nome "Maria" seja permitido pelo programa?

Quero que qualquer outra palavra que eu colocar (ex: João) o usuário não consiga prosseguir com o término do Formulário.

```
nome = input("Coloque seu nome: ") 
cpf = input("Coloque seu CPF: ")
endereco = input("Coloque seu Endereço: ") 
idade = input("Coloque sua idade: ")
altura = input("Coloque sua altura: ") 
telefone = input("Coloque seu telefone: ")

print (nome, "você tem", idade, "anos e", altura, "de altura.") 
while nome == "Maria":
    print("Seu telefone é: ", telefone)
    print("Seu cpf é: ", cpf)
    print("Seu endereço é: ", endereco) 
else:
    print("Nome diferente.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos criar uma lista de nomes que serão permitidos:

```
ALLOWED_NAMES = ["maria"]
```

Perceba que o nome está todo em caixa baixa. É importante para uma validação futura.

Definimos a variável `nome` e fazemos a leitura enquanto o valor não pertencer à lista de nomes permitidos:

```
nome = ""

# Enquanto o nome for inválido:
while nome.lower() not in ALLOWED_NAMES:

  # Pergunta o nome do usuário:
  nome = input("Coloque seu nome: ")

  # Verifica se o nome é permitido:
  if nome.lower() not in ALLOWED_NAMES:
    print("Usuário não permitido")
```

Percebe que no `while` verificamos o valor de `nome.lower()`? Isso para que o usuário possa digitar variações do mesmo nome: maria, Maria, MARIA, etc. Para a validação, convertemos o nome para caixa baixa e verificamos se pertence à lista. Somente quando o nome for válido, damos continuidade no programa.

#### Código completo

```
ALLOWED_NAMES = ["maria"]

nome = ""

# Enquanto o nome for inválido:
while nome.lower() not in ALLOWED_NAMES:

  # Pergunta o nome do usuário:
  nome = input("Coloque seu nome: ")

  # Verifica se o nome é permitido:
  if nome.lower() not in ALLOWED_NAMES:
    print("Usuário não permitido")

# Pergunta o CPF:
cpf = input("Coloque seu CPF: ")

# Pergunta o endereço:
endereco = input("Coloque seu endereço: ") 

# Pergunta a idade:
idade = input("Coloque sua idade: ")

# Pergunta a altura:
altura = input("Coloque sua altura: ") 

# Pergunta o telefone:
telefone = input("Coloque seu telefone: ")

print (nome, "você tem", idade, "anos e", altura, "de altura.") 
print("Seu telefone é: ", telefone)
print("Seu CPF é: ", cpf)
print("Seu endereço é: ", endereco)
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Frpi/0).

> **Nota**: Manter os nomes permitidos em uma lista não é trivial para a lógica em si, apenas mantém o programa fácil de ser expandido para situações caso sejam permitidos mais de um nome. Se *Paulo* passasse a ser um nome permitido, bastaria adicioná-lo na lista e não escrever mais linhas de código implementando um novo `if else`.